# Bank account class with 2 child class not showing appropriate error message

Tags: java, class

Need help with my school work, I'm very much new to programming. So the requirements are:

> Class Account, change the visibility of all data to protected. Change the withdraw method so that it becomes an abstract method. This action will necessitate you declaring the class as abstract. Deposits should work the same way in OnLineAccount and SavingsAccount so make sure they cannot override their parent’s version.
>
> The OnLineAccount class has one additional attribute to that of class Account, minimumBalance. All instances of OnLineAccount are created with the minimumBalance amount set to $500. If transactions of any OnLineAccount cause the balance to go below minimumBalance, a $25 fee is subtracted from the account balance. Override the `toString` method to display everything the Account `toString` displays plus a message dependent upon the balance. If the balance is below the minimumBalance, a message stating that a $25 fee has been already been subtracted needs to alert the customer. Use the parent class `toString` to do most of the work.
>
> The SavingsAccount class has one additional attribute to that of class Account, overdraft. All instances of SavingsAccount are created with the overdraft amount set to -$1000. An overdraft amount is the amount an object of SavingsAccount class may allow the balance to go to. Implement the withdraw method so that overdrafts are allowed up to the amount stored in overdraft. Any withdrawals that allow the balance to drop below zero and up to the overdraft amount are allowed but the overdraft fee of $30 is incurred each time a transaction causes the balance to be below zero.
>   Override the `toString` method to display everything the Account `toString` 
>   displays plus a message dependent upon the balance. If the balance is below zero, a message stating that the person is in overdraft and a $30 fee has been already been incurred. Use the parent class `toString` to do most of the work.
>
> Create a driver class with an array of 5 objects of Account, being some instances of the child classes OnLineAccount or SavingsAccount. Systematically test the full functionality of both child classes.

================================

So I created 4 class file, it shows all account info but also showing negative balance which should be an error message instead cause balance should not be less than $500.

Here are my class files:

Account class:

```
    import java.text.NumberFormat;
    import java.util.Locale;

    public abstract class Account {

    private static int defaultAccountNo = 12345;
    protected String owner;
    protected int accountNo;
    protected double balance;

    protected Account(String owner, double intialDeposit){
        this.owner = owner;
        this.balance = intialDeposit;
        defaultAccountNo++;
        this.accountNo = defaultAccountNo;
    }

    public final boolean deposit(double amount){
        if(amount<=0){
            System.err.println("Negative amount can't be deposited");
            return false;
        }
        balance = balance+amount;
        return true;
    }

    protected abstract boolean withdrawl(double amount);

    public String getBalance(){
        return formatter.format(balance);
    }
    public int getAccountNo(){
        return accountNo;
    }

    public void setOwner(String owner){
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    protected void addInterest(){
        double interest = 0.05*balance;
        balance = balance+interest;
    }

    public boolean equals(Account account){
        if(this.owner.equalsIgnoreCase(account.owner))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

    public String toString(){
        return "AccountNo: "+accountNo+"\nBalance: "+formatter.format(balance);
     } 


   }
```

OnlineAccount Class:

```
public class OnLineAccount extends Account{

public OnLineAccount(String owner, double intialDeposit) {
    super(owner, intialDeposit);
}

private static final double MINIMUM_BALANCE = 500;


public boolean withdrawl(double amount){
    if(amount<0){
        System.err.println("Negative amount cannot be withdrawn");
        return false;
    }
    if((balance-amount)<0){
        System.err.println("Not enought balance");
        return false;
    }
    balance = balance-amount;
    if(balance<MINIMUM_BALANCE)
        balance = balance - 25;
    return true;
}

public String toString(){
    String returnString;
    if(balance<500){
        returnString = super.toString()+"\n$25 fee has been already been subtracted as account balance reached below minimum";
        return returnString;
    }
    return super.toString();

  }


}
```

SavingsAccount Class:

```
 public class SavingsAccount extends Account{

    private static final double DEFAULT_OVERDRAFT = -1000;

    public SavingsAccount(String owner, double intialDeposit) {
        super(owner, intialDeposit);
    }

    public boolean withdrawl(double amount) {
        if(amount<0){
            System.err.println("Negative amount cannot be withdrawn");
            return false;
        }
        if((balance-amount-30)<DEFAULT_OVERDRAFT){
            System.err.println("Not enough balance, overdraft reached");

        }
        if((balance-amount)<0){
            balance = balance-amount-30;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String toString(){
        String returnString;
        if(balance<500){
            returnString = super.toString()+"\nYour are in overdraft and $30 fee has been already been subtracted.";
            return returnString;
        }
        return super.toString();

      }

   }
```

TestAccount Class:

```
    import java.util.Random;
    public class TestAccount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random ran = new Random();

        Account[] accountArray = new Account[5];
        Account acc1 = new OnLineAccount("Bill", 1000);
        Account acc2 = new OnLineAccount("Susan", 1500);
        Account acc3 = new SavingsAccount("William", 2500);
        Account acc4 = new SavingsAccount("Bill", 9000);
        Account acc5 = new SavingsAccount("Bruce", 1355);

        accountArray[0] = acc1;
        accountArray[1] = acc2;
        accountArray[2] = acc3;
        accountArray[3] = acc4;
        accountArray[4] = acc5;

        for(int i=0; i<accountArray.length; i++){
            System.out.println("Initial details of Account....");
            System.out.println(accountArray[i]);
            System.out.println("After some transactions..");
            accountArray[i].deposit(ran.nextInt(300));
            accountArray[i].withdrawl(ran.nextInt(3000
   ));
            System.out.println("Balance: "+accountArray[i].getBalance());
            System.out.println("After adding the interest for the year....");
            accountArray[i].addInterest();
            System.out.println("Balance: "+accountArray[i].getBalance());
            System.out.println(); // for blank line
        }

        System.out.println("Checking for Duplicates now....");
        for(int i=0; i<accountArray.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<i; j++){
                if(accountArray[i].equals(accountArray[j])){
                    System.out.println("Account "+accountArray[i].getAccountNo()+
                            " and "+accountArray[j].getAccountNo()+" are duplicates");
                }
            }
          }

       }

    }
```

I spent hours with no luck. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.
This is my first post here.

The output I'm getting is (Account no 12350 is getting negative balance...):

[image: Account no 12350 is getting negative balance...]

Comment: Just saying: this is a great "first" question. You provide a lot of detail; and it is clear that you dont want us to do your homework for you. Nonetheless, it might be helpful to show the output of your test program; and point out the exact place where you get an unexpected result.
And another hint: you might consider to throw an exception in your error scenarios (instead of printing to stderr and return false). That has one big advantage: your program stops right there, at the first "error situation".

Comment: Agreed - good 1st question.  Before I answer, I think it ***might be*** this - when you output *following* the transactions - you directly call `accountArray[i].getBalance()` - bypassing the part where you warn about invalid balances / fees in `toString()` - I think if you output using `accountArray[i].toString()` again - you will see your warning messages.  Also - a tip - when you're getting behaviour you don't understand - replace the random values with fixed values temporarily while you debug

Comment: Thanks very much @J Richard Snape & EddyG, things are shaping up a bit after applying your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Negative amounts are possibile in your code.

Imagine this scenario with an online account.

Robert has 3000 dollars. He withdraws 2990 dollars. There are only 10 dollars remaing.

Seeing that 10 dollars is less than the minimum amount, you subract 25 dollars.
So Robert will have -15 dollars on his account.

Comment: in other words you should review `public boolean withdrawl(double amount)` function. you should not let it withdraw if amount is bigger than the balance

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for your help. It's now working perfectly with all error messages showing up. I added toString() after getBalance() as  J Richard Snape suggested and all OK now.

As Richard said, getBalance() was bypassing all warning.

Output now:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Negative amounts are possible because you have a bound that is higher than some of the person's initial amount deposited.

With the deposit and withdrawal in your block of code, you can withdraw into an amount that causes the person to have a balance in the negative.

```
accountArray[i].withdrawl(ran.nextInt(3000
            ));
```